# High order функции

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять как работать с объектом или массивом функций.

К примеру есть функция и я ожидаю, что переданные аргументы, будут перебраны и по очереди вызваны. К примеру как map или forEach.

```
const Myfunctions = { func1, func2, func3 }

const allCallFunctions = ({...functions}) => {
     functions.map(func => func());
}
```

Если может кто объяснить, то как для чайника или если нет желания расписывать, просто ссылку где почитать.

p.s. с high order функциями знаком, но под такой расклад ничего не нашёл, самому мозгов не хватило. Спасибо.

Comment: Деструктуризация абсолютно бессмыслена. С ней или без неё, но в `functions` будет **объект** и естественно, что методы `map()` или `forEach()` тут не помогут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

хорошая фантазия, **но** метод `map` работает только с массивами, а Вы пытались скормить ему деструктуризованный объект. тем более `map` всегда возвращает новый массив (для этого он и предназначен). а у Вас в коде `map` возвращает в никуда новый массив с результатами выполненных функций.

решения проблемы на мой взгляд:

**а)** передавать как аргумент массив с функциями, а не объект и вызывать их через `forEach`, например:

```
const Myfunctions = [ func1, func2, func3 ];

const allCallFunctions = functions => {
    functions.forEach(func => func());
}
```

**б)** передавать объект с функциями (как у Вас и было первоначально), но вызывать их через цикл итерации объектов, например:

```
const Myfunctions = { func1, func2, func3 };

const allCallFunctions = ({...functions}) => {
    for (let func in functions) {
        func();
    }
}
```

или же перебрать аргумент `functions` через `Object.values` (переделать в массив) и тоже вызывать через `forEach`

Comment: Если уж на то пошло, то в варианте **б** - `for ... in` , а не `for ... of`

Comment: @Deonis, кстати, да. как-то машинально ошибся. исправил

Comment: Чтобы принимать `...functions` передавать надо будет не массив.

Comment: Помог вариант **А**, но с дополнением `const funcArray = Object.values(Myfunctions)` и уже `forEach` по значениям).